# Downloading a Google Play homepage

Tags: java, android, html, urlconnection

I'm trying to download a page from the new Google Play market and seem to get strange results. I use the url `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package.name` and the following method:

```
private static String downloadString(final URL url) throws IOException {
    final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(final String hostname,
                final SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);

    String html;

    try {
        final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        final ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        html = new String(baf.toByteArray());

    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    return html;
}
```

The result doen't contain the description, the changelogs or anything important, but my html knowledge isn't good enough to understand what exactly is beeing downloaded. I put the downloaded source code [here](http://pastebin.com/n7CMRyv7) for any one interested. It's 10 times smaller than the desired page which is any Google Play app page.

My question is, how do I obtain the original app page's source?

Answer (score 1):

What you got from your method was probably right. Google likes to load in resources using javascript to improve performance, and all that Javascript is compiled so it's unreadable as all hell.

So when you download the page you probably receive the a very small amount of HTML, and you mentioned that the change log etc. aren't present? That would mean that they are being loaded in using some kind of client side runtime, most likely javascript.

To download this you're going to need a browser or library take can execute Javascript, CSS and layout the HTML.

Maybe check libraries like Jambi? I know QT has a QWebView Component that uses Webkit but I don't know if this will run Javascript.

Hope that at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and "Oh my God, why?". This was so much simpler whith the Android Market.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing e.g. the Firebug plugin in your browser or any other tool that lets you monitor http traffic while you access the page. Then you can see which calls are made to load the actual data. You can probably just grab those Urls instead.